# Input numbers into array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, input, numbers

I'm very beginner of programming.
I'm trying to make program which is able to input 10 numbers.
Therefore I could make this kind of program:

```
while True:
        s = input('Enter 10 numbers : ')
        if len(s) == 10:
            break
        else:
            print('Retype your 10 personal numbers!!')
print('Done')
```

However, I want to input numbers into array like `s[10]`?
For instance, if I input `'1234567890'`, it is input like `s[0]=1`, `s[1]=2`,...,`s[10]=0`.

Please enlighten me on the specifics.

Comment: Im assuming you want to store each of the 10 numbers entered?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. And exactly.

Answer (score 4):

if `s='1234567890'` then you can turn `s` into a list of digits with a simple list comprehension:

```
s = [int(d) for d in s]
```

then

```
>>> s
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
>>> s[9]
0
```

(`s[10]` is out of range BTW :))

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I'll try it. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

or you can just make a simple update in your program i.e just declare s as the empty list first.
It is :

```
s=[]
while True:
    s = input('Enter 10 numbers : ')
    if len(s) == 10:
        break
    else:
        print('Retype your 10 personal numbers!!')
print('Done')
```

Comment: It's easy to understand for me. Thank you so much for your answer.